# A calculation on the relation between gamma-matrices and total antisymmetric tensor

Tags: dirac-matrices, clifford-algebra

In some papers I found the following relations:
$$\left[\gamma^N,\left[\gamma^I,\gamma^J\right]\right]=4\left(\eta^{NI}\gamma^J-\eta^{NJ}\gamma^I\right)$$
$$\left\{\gamma^N,\left[\gamma^I,\gamma^J\right]\right\}=-4i\epsilon^{NIJK}\gamma^5\gamma_K$$
Within the two equations, I can figure out the first one myself, and according to which we could find that the Writer is using the sign convention $(+,-,-,-)$. For the second one I have totally no idea how it comes out. Could anyone who can help me about this?
In the formula, 
$\gamma^N$ is the gamma matrix in 4 dimensional inner space;
$\eta^{NI}$ is the metric in Minkovski (inner/ Lorentz) space;
$\epsilon^{NIJK}$ is the to total antisymmetric tensor with $\epsilon^{0123}=1$;
$\gamma^5=-i\gamma^0\gamma^1\gamma^2\gamma^3$ as usual.

Comment: Do you know (5) of [these](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_matrices#Miscellaneous_identities)?

Comment: @CosmasZachos Hello Cosmas, thanks for your kind help, now I can figure out how this formula come out!